# Is there a name/pattern for classes which call abstract handler methods

Tags: design-patterns, interface, handler

Imagine two classes `TypeAServer` and `TypeBServer` which implement some sort of functionality and need to call methods in case of some events. Apart from providing discrete callback functions I can think of two slightly different approaches when I want to implement composite behavior:

```py
class TypeAServer(ABC):
    def __init__(self):
        do some stuff

    @abstractmethod
    def on_type_a_event(self, event):
        ''' will be called when event type A occurs '''

    def some_message_generating_method(self):
        ...
        self._handler.on_type_a_event(e)

class TypeBServer(ABC):
    def __init__(self):
        do some stuff

    @abstractmethod
    def on_type_b_event(self, event):
        ''' will be called when event type A occurs '''

    def some_message_generating_method(self):
        ...
        self._handler.on_type_b_event(e)

class CompositeServer(TypeAServer, TypeBServer):
    def __init__(self):
        TypeAServer.__init__(self)
        TypeBServer.__init__(self)

    def on_type_a_event(self, event):
        # implement reaction of event type A

    def on_type_b_event(self, event):
        # implement reaction of event type B
```

In this case I just inherit classes with abstract methods in order to implement the wanted behavior.

However - when I don't want to inherit `TypeAServer` and `TypeBServer` directly I can also go for a composition based approach like this:

```py
class TypeAServer:
    class Handler(ABC):
        @abstractmethod
        def on_type_a_event(self, event):
            ''' will be called when event type A occurs '''

    def __init__(self, handler):
        self._handler = handler
        # do some other stuff

    def some_message_generating_method(self):
        ...
        self._handler.on_type_a_event(e)

class TypeBServer:
    class Handler(ABC):
        @abstractmethod
        def on_type_a_event(self, event):
            ''' will be called when event type A occurs '''

    def __init__(self, handler):
        self._handler = handler

    def some_message_generating_method(self):
        ...
        self._handler.on_type_b_event(e)

class CompositeServer(TypeAServer.Handler, TypeBServer.Handler):
    def __init__(self):
        self.type_a_server = TypeAServer(handler=self)
        self.type_b_server = TypeAServer(handler=self)

    def on_type_a_event(self, event):
        # implement reaction of event type A

    def on_type_b_event(self, event):
        # implement reaction of event type B
```

This second example is quite similar to the first one but it has some well known benefits (see *composition over inheritance*):

- I can decide when I set up the server instances
- I can even add more dynamically
- Testing is simpler
- Name collisions of internally called methods are less likely

My Question is now: I know terms like *composition* and *interface* - but is there a *pattern* for "injecting" an object which implements a "handler interface" on construction (in contrast to implicitly providing the handler through inheritance)?

Comment: Strategy pattern? That was the first coming to my mind. Maybe doesn't fit 100%

Answer (score 0):

The change made to `TypeAServer` (and `TypeBServer`), having a separate [listener](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event-driven_programming#Event_handlers) [object](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern), can be considered a form of [dependency injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection): instead of the server "creating" its own handler (read: using itself as the handler), you provide one to its constructor.

Then the creation of a `CompositeServer` is two sorts of composition at once:

1. It combines two handlers: the implementation is via multiple inheritance, but it could equally well be implemented using the [adapter pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter_pattern) where two handlers share underlying state.
2. It composes itself from two servers, justifying its name.

(Unsolicited advice follows.)  It's not clear from this much code why you wouldn't use just the first point (and call it `CompositeHandler`), leaving the server *construction* to the client.  That client could itself compose the servers and handler, but it wouldn't have to do so.